# set user-agent header on serving index.html, express.js

Tags: javascript, express, http-headers

I need to set my custom http `'User-Agent` header when I'm rendering my `index.html` page in **Express.js** app.

This doesn't help:

```
req.headers['user-agent'] = 'myHeader';
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The User-Agent header is sent by an HTTP client(browser) and is meant to be read by a server, for e.g., for [**Content Negotiation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation).
You cannot set a request header in a response, it can only be read. Moreover, the req object(**IncomingMessage**) passed to `createServer()` callback is a `Readable` stream.

However, a request can be **initiated** with a customer header using:

```
var headers = {'User-Agent': 'Ryan Dahl'};

http.request({hostname: 'nodejs.org', headers: headers}, function(res) {

});
```

Comment: so it's impossible to make something ``app.use(function (req, res, next) { req.headers['user-agent'] = 'myHeader'; next(); })`` ?